# Windows Server Migration - find which c plusplus redist installations are necessary

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, migration, visual-c++, asp

here's the situation:

We have an older Winserver 2012 VM that we want to migrate to 2019. This VM has a bunch of IIS / ASP sites that were written by an intern about 6-8 years ago, and apparently need to remain functional under the new environment. We see pretty much every Visual C++ Redist installation ever available on the original server, and are wondering how we determine which of them are necessary.

So, I have a twofold question -
Is there any harm or security concern with having all of these installed on a server?
And
Would there be any way to determine which of them are required, save for manually inspecting each sites file system?

Admittedly, I never used ASP much in my web dev days. If this question is way off target, I will delete it.

Comment: It's like the old days of "DLL Hell", with many versions of the same DLL. sigh

Comment: Funny you say that, as I'm digging through DLL's with dotpeek right now :)